# Начало и конец недели по её номеру

Tags: php

Зная номер недели, как узнать дату начала недели и конца (для текущего года)?

Comment: Нашел ответ для вас http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Привет, накидал "на коленке" вариант длинный, за то наглядный и простой для понимания.

```
$d = new DateTime( '2015-01-01' ); // задаём начало отсчёта
$d->modify('+5 week'); // выбираем нужную неделю 
$d->modify('this week'); // первый день
echo $d->format( 'd F Y' ), "\n";
$d->modify('next week -1 day'); // последний день
echo $d->format( 'd F Y' ), "\n";
```

Если будут вопросы пишите